# Getting user input and stop looping when nessesary C

Tags: c, user-input

I need to get an input integer from a user between a given range. I need to get their low and high. But the loop is not stopping and i have no idea why. I thought my conditions were good but the loop wont stop.

```
int     obtainNumberBetween (const char* descriptionCPtr, int low, int high) {
  char  line[MAX_LINE];
  int   entry;
//  #define     MAX_LINE    256

  // YOUR CODE HERE
 do
  {
    printf("Please enter the lowest number in the range (%d-%d):\n " ,RANGE_LOWEST ,RANGE_HIGHEST);
    fgets(line, 256, stdin);
    low = atoi(line);
    printf ("The value entered is %d\n", low);

  }
  while  ( (entry < low) || (entry > high) );

return(entry);

}
```

Sample output of what it should be:

```
Please enter the lowest number in the range (0-32767): -6
Please enter the lowest number in the range (0-32767): 1
Please enter the highest number in the range (1-32767): 0
Please enter the highest number in the range (1-32767): 32768
Please enter the highest number in the range (1-32767): 512
```

Comment: what entry is doing? what value you comparing inside while?

Comment: Well the user input needs to be either less than 'low', or is greater than 'high', then the user is asked for another number. After the user finally enters a legal number, this function returns that number.

Comment: low = atoi(line); you are overwriting on low, did you meant to write on to entry? because you are not doing anything to entry but your modifying low, by this you lost your lowest value.

Comment: I was trying to add the value I got from the user input into the variable low lol. because later on when i ask the user to input a HIGH value, the low needs to be their low. If that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Your `entry` variable is not initialized. So this line is invoking an undefined behavior:

```
while  ( (entry < low) || (entry > high) )
```

Perhaps you should assign user input to the `entry` instead of `low`.

Comment: But if I do that, how will I obtain high? I need to get 2 integers from the user which is low and high

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to `entry`.
The loop doesn't stop because `entry` hasn't been initialised and therefore the condition of your while loop is always true.

change 
`low = atoi(line);`
to

```
entry = atop(line);
```

and then add

```
low = atoi(entry);
```

after the while loop.

Comment: did you mean entry = atoi(line); ?

Comment: also how do i get the highest value? The same thing?